# Drupal Commons: Active sub theme of Commons Origins is intermittently not working (base theme is showing)

Tags: theming, 7

I have a staging site and a production site.  The production site does not currently have a DNS record and I currently have a hosts entry for it  (134.x.x.x subdomain.example.com).

I have a subtheme of Commons Origins theme called exampletheme.   Exampletheme works fine on the staging server (which has a DNS record and no hosts file entry); but, when I migrated it over to the production server, I can only sporadically get the subtheme to show.  Sometimes it reappears if I activate random themes (including commons origins), when I re-activate exampletheme, it will show for a while.   But, eventually it goes away and I am back to looking at Commons Origins theme.

Two other factors, while the problem is existing, a drush status shows that the current theme is exampletheme.  Also I have an error_log in commons_origins_preprocess_html and exampletheme_preprocess_html.  It shows that commons_origins_preprocess_html does fire , while exampletheme_preprocess_html does not.

In addition, I have made a copy of exampletheme with a different name, activated it and it has the same problems.

I have checked the permissions on the theme files and they are the same as the commons_origins theme.

Any insight into this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the theme_registry... entries in the cache table were not getting cleared for some reason.  I ran the following in mysql prompt:

delete from cache where cid like 'theme_%';

It's been working fine for hours now